# Parse - Attendance register - help to get the framework correct

Tags: parse-platform, schema

I'm new to parse and I'm trying to create an attendance app using HTML/Javascript with parse as the backend.

I have some conceptual and technical implementation questions before I delve deep in to ensure I don't go down the wrong track.

I have two objects (tables): one contains the students' names, ID and group (call this `Students`):

```
StudentID   |   Name   |  GroupID
```

The second will just be a record of the attendance (call this `Register`) which will just have date, a letter to represent Present, Absent or Late, and some form of 'foreign key':

```
Date   |   Present  |   StudentForeignKey
```

The plan for implementation is to query parse for any students belonging to a group and see if there is already a 'register' for that group on the selected date. If so, use that data as the starting point otherwise it's a brand new entry for that group+date. Then the user makes changes and saves it back to parse.

My questions:

1. For the 'foreign key', should I insert the `Students` object into `Register` (e.g. `myRegister.set("StudentForeignKey", myStudentObject`) or should I insert the StudentID ((e.g. `myRegister.set("StudentForeignKey", StudentID`)? My concern here is whether it will affect queries later on. (Currently I have done the former method but think it might affect Q2).

[image: This is how the Register looks]

2. I am not clear how exactly to get **ALL** students from `Students` for a given `GroupID` and **ONLY** those items from `Register` where the `StudentForeignKey` matches. Would I have to do this as two queries?

So, first query is:

```
var studentlist = Parse.Object.extend("Students");
var query = new Parse.Query(studentlist);
query.equalTo("GroupID", 4);
query.find({...
```

The above gives me all students with GroupID=4.

But then how do I get the `Register` entries where the `Student` matches (for a given date)? PS: I saw some old posts that say matching on pointers does not work...is that still the case?

I do not want to include `GroupID` in `Register` (which, in theory, would allow me to filter those student in the group of interest) as the group can change and so I want attendance to be linked to the student.

3. Finally, the intention is for the user to hit a save button to save ALL the changes made. In my mind I see it as an 'array' of values to store in the database (either new items or changes to existing items). Is there a way to do this update in one shot (a bit like the update query in MS Access)?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use more classes. I'd also use pointers (to answer the first question) and relationships (to answer the second). Pointers are basically IDs in a wrapper to make them easier to use.

I'd actually make a `Group` class. This class would have a relationship to `Student` so you can easily get and manage all of the students in the `Group`.

The `Student` class can remain basically as it is, though it can have a pointer to `Group` instead of an ID (if you need it or it helps with other navigation).

The `Register` class I would give a pointer to `Group` and a date, but I'd then give it a relationship to an `AttendanceRecord` class. The `Register` can also hold other details about anything related, like who took the register on that date.

`AttendanceRecord` is a simple collation class and holds the attendance status and a pointer to the `Student`.

With this you can easily navigate from a group to the students. Given a group you can easily fetch registers for that group on a given date. From the register you can easily fetch all of the attendance for all students (see also `include` on the query).

Registers form a historical record of what happened. Each time a new register is taken it uses the students from the associated group. As the group changes over time the registers will reflect this.

Parse does offer a `Parse.Object.saveAll` function that you can use to save an array of objects. You need to be careful with this when using relationships as you need the objects to exist before you add them to a relationship and then save the relationship.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have drawn this out on paper! Am I correct that this will work in the following way: Do a query on Register class for a given Group and Date. This will pull in the related Attendance Records (using the include query). But how do I then get the Student records related to the Attendance Record? Do I do something like query.include(["AttendanceRecord.Student"]);?

Comment: Not quite, you can't use `include` over a relationship, so you would need to make 2 requests, 1 for the Register and another for the Attendance (and include the students). As a side note you can navigate multiple levels of pointers with a key path in `include`.

Comment: Did I miss something - doing it that way would give me all attendance records for a given date+group but would NOT give me ALL students for a given group too? Correct? My aim was to get all students from a group and any associated attendance data for that group for the given date. Sorry if I am missing the point!

Comment: Also, If I'm doing 2 queries anyway, can I not do one query to get all students in a group and another to get all attendance records for a given group?

Comment: My option would be to query for the register (for a group and date) and then from there query the relationship to get all the attendance records (and associated students). There are many ways this could potentially work, I would advocate more objects and requests to simplify the objects and allow them the be smaller and more focussed.